# Vector of pointers and erasing a specific value

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

I am having a little bit of trouble with finding a way to erase a value from a vector of pointer.

I have a vector `std::vect<MyClass*> myVect` which contains pointers to objects `o1, o2,...` in a specific order. I am having a bit of trouble to find how to delete the entry of one specific object, for example `o1`

I tried

```
void remove(MyClass C)
{
    myVect.erase( std::find_if( myVect.begin(), myVect.end(), [&](MyClass* W) 
   {return &C == W;} ) );
}
```

but my bool lambda never returns true (verified with assert) . Is there something I am doing wrong? (I must say that I am not really familiar with Lambda functions/tors)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Obviously, as C is passed by value and you compare the address of that object with an address inside `myVect` it will essentially never matches. Maybe, you want to compare item values or otherwise you probably want to pass a pointer to your remove function.

Comment: try `C == *W` as the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function accepts a `MyClass` by value as `C`, so it's always working with a freshly made instance in the function's local scope.

Your test function is checking `&C == W;`, but it's impossible for the address of `C` to match the address stored in the `vector` (unless `remove` added it earlier).

If you really want the test to be by address, you probably want to accept your argument by reference, `void remove(MyClass& C)` in which case some other part of your code could pass an existing object by reference whose pointer might be in the `vector`.

More likely, you want the test to be by value, in which case, for efficiency, you probably want code more like this:

```
void remove(const MyClass& C)  // Receive by const reference to avoid pointless copy
{
    // Testing C == *W tests the value pointed to, not the pointers themselves
    myVect.erase( std::find_if( myVect.begin(), myVect.end(), [&](MyClass* W) 
   {return C == *W;} ) );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I will do. I thought about this quickly , but the way my class is made ( Players around a table of poker ) I will have to add an unique ID to my "Player" Class so I can compare them and I wanted to avoid doing this (As I could have many players with the same name so I can't really compare it like that). Guess I will have to!